# what are the different ways to fetch data from IoT Hub(microsoft azure)?

Tags: azure, iot, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

What are the ways to store refined/filtered data from Microsoft azure IoT Hub at another servers/cloud storages(like AWS)?

Comment: We are working on one of the project, currently our data is coming at the IoT Hub from different devices. We are building an application to analyze the data stored at IoT hub. The application we are building is not hosted at azure yet. What are the possible ways/approaches to fetch this data, so that I can store relevant data at new server using the best approach/way.

Comment: As per the requirement of the project, we need to deal with real time data, backup and restore will take time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is an example of the *warm path* for your telemetry stream. It is based on the new preview feature for archiving ingested data at the Event Hub. Note, that this preview feature is not built in the Azure IoT Hub, so all events are routed to the custom Event Hub. The period of the archiving events into the Azure Storage Blob (avro blob) can be configured from 1 - 15 minutes.

[image: Telemetry Warm Path]

Comment: Do you have more info about the archive feature? Wouldn't mind replacing some of our ASA-based cold storage archiving with something like this.

Comment: - more details about the new preview Archive feature of the Azure Event Hub:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-archive-overview

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to accomplish this and I think that there are no right answers to your question.  Anyways, here are possible options:

**Push to AWS:**
IoT HuB => Stream Analytics => Azure Storage or SQL Database => Azure Functions => AWS storage

**Pull from AWS:**
IoT HuB => Stream Analytics => Azure Storage or SQL Database <= AWS Lambda => AWS storage

I realize that is vague but you didn't provide much details.

Answer (score 2):

WebJobs, Azure Functions and Azure Stream Analytics (ASA) can be used along with a slew of intermediate storage options depending on your needs. For a straight up filtered stream you could use IoT Hub routes to blob storage, then a WebJob or Azure Function triggered on the blob storage to push to AWS.

SQL Azure can struggle under certain high volume situations and ASA is expensive for what it is unless you need actual real time analytics (about $85/SU/month with MS recommending 3 SU's for production ASA jobs).